# Server Side Encryption in to_csv function

Tags: amazon-s3, dask

I'm getting this error while using to_csv("s3://mys3bucket/result.csv")

```
Exception: [Errno Write Failed: mys3bucket/result.csv/2489.part]
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

It may have been caused because Dask is not using server-side encryption. Please tell me how can I make it use SSE or some other method to successfully write the file to the s3 bucket

Comment: Have you read the [docs](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/remote-data-services.html)? You should use the `storage_options` parameter. I usually save the files locally and upload using `botocore`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @user32185's comment, for controling SSE via dask, your call should look something like this:

```
to_csv("s3://mys3bucket/result.csv",
       storage_option={'s3_additional_kwargs':
           {'ServerSideEncryption': 'AES256'}})
```

where the specifics of SSE with s3fs are detailed [here](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#serverside-encryption). Note that you may also require other keywords from the same docs page, for credentials, storage zone, etc. The parameters are passed to the [`S3FileSystem` constructor](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#s3fs.core.S3FileSystem), and you can delve into the boto docs to see what everything means.